# how to use sortBy in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I want to sort the data class in kotlin. I tried to sort by ascending order, but it not sorting correctly.

**ProductVariant.kt**

```
data class ProductVariant(
    val strength: String? = null,
    val quantity: String? = null,
    val subscription: String? = null
)
```

First I need to sort by **strength** value then after sorting, I want to sort by **quantity** value in ascending order. I tried some code to sort first by **strength** it's not working.

**Options.kt**

```
fun main() {
    val list = getUnSortedDataList()

    val sortedList = list.sortedBy {
        it.subscription
    }

    sortedList.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}

fun getUnSortedDataList(): List<ProductVariant> {
    return listOf(
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "12")
    )
}
```

Getting output through above code is

```
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=14, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=8, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=14, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=10, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=2, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=4, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=6, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=10, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=12, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=14, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=2, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=4, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=6, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=10, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=12, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=2, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=6, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=8, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=12, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=8, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=4, subscription=1)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=14, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=8, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=14, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=10, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=2, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=4, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=6, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=10, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=12, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=14, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=2, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=4, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=6, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=10, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=12, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=2, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=6, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=8, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=12, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=8, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=4, subscription=12)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=14, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=8, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=14, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=10, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=2, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=4, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=6, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=10, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=12, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=14, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=2, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=4, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=6, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=10, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=12, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=2, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=6, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=8, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=12, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=8, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=4, subscription=3)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=14, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=8, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=14, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=10, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=2, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=4, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=6, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=10, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=12, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=14, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=2, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=4, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=6, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=10, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=12, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=2, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=6, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=8, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=12, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=8, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=4, subscription=6)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=14, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=8, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=14, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=10, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=2, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=4, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=6, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=10, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=12, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=25, quantity=14, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=2, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=4, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=6, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=10, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=12, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=2, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=6, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=8, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=12, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=50, quantity=8, subscription=9)
ProductVariant(strength=75, quantity=4, subscription=9)
```

I want like this

**Expected output**

```
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "4", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "25", quantity = "14", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "4", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "50", quantity = "14", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "2", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "4", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "6", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "8", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "10", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "12", subscription = "12"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "1"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "3"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "6"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "9"),
        ProductVariant(strength = "75", quantity = "14", subscription = "12")
```

Comment: For future reference, in your example code, make your list to sort just a few items, like 5. Unless you're discussing some new sorting algo for millions of items, the problem & solution is the same for 5 items vs 50 vs 50,000.

Comment: @aneroid sure for next time. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(
  compareBy<ProductVariant> {         // or compareByDescending
    it.strength?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
  }.thenBy {                          // or thenByDescending
    it.quantity?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0   // or java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE
  }
)
```

Edit: Changed from *toInt()* to *toIntOrNull()* as suggested by [Ivo Beckers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514861/ivo-beckers) (see his comment below).

Comment: Made adjustment for the case _strength_ or _quantity_ would be _null_.

Comment: can you please tell me why do you use 0?

Comment: Depending on _0_ or _java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE_ the item will be sorted before all others or after all others. Some applications show items with null value in the column ordered at the beginning of a table, some at the end.

Comment: I would suggest using `toIntOrNull()` instead. Now the program will crash if the string happens to be not an int

Comment: @lukas.j @IvoBeckers is there any performance impact if we use `it.strength?.toIntOrNull()`or `it.quantity?.toIntOrNull()` i.e. the value is string and we are converting into `int`?

Answer (score 2):

You sort strings, not numbers and by default strings are sorted in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). You just need to convert these values to integers:

```kotlin
list.sortedBy { it.strength?.toInt() }
```

Comment: it printing the strength value in correct way. But now I want to sort quantity value in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sortedWith](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html) + [compareBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html):

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.strength?.toInt() ?: 0 }, { it.quantity?.toInt() ?: 0 }, { it.subscription?.toInt() ?: 0 }))
```